# Windows UWP Webview with Local Relative URLs

Tags: html, webview, uwp, windows-10

I am developing an application that uses a webview for the primary interface. Upon startup, the program loads a page that is included in the `Content` directory of the project, complete with external style sheets and scripts and they all load properly. The code to load is:

```
webViewer.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Content\\landing.html"));
```

And the content of `landing.html` is as follows. It all works properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <base href="ms-appx-web://58377ramsays.studios.chordwriter/Content/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

A problem has arisen when I try to use `NavigateToString()` to load rendered content into the viewer and try to use these style sheets, and specifically FontAwesome. I am loading the file using this code:

```
webViewer.NavigateToString(song.RenderHtml(appSettings));
```

And the `RenderHtml()` function looks partially like this:

```
string content = @"<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href=""ms-appx-web://58377ramsays.studios.chordwriter/Content/"" />
    <link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""css/font-awesome.min.css"" />
    <style type=""text/css"">
      body { font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        margin: 15px;
        font-size: " + settings.Values["settingsFontSize"] +  @"pt; }
      span.flat { margin: -4px -2px;
        font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode','Lucida Grande',sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        height: 0.9em;
        display: inline-block; }
      h3 { font-size: 1.5em; }
      th a { text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #127690; }
      td a { text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #000; }
      i { color: #000;
        width: 1em; }
    </style>
  </head>
    <body>";
// Rest of rendering function.
```

However I cannot seem to get FontAwesome to load properly. As far as I can tell the `font-awesome.min.css` is loading properly, because the icons' `i` tags are the right size (square blocks) but they are blank, meaning the font file is not being loaded. I tried using the `<base>` tag but that does not seem to work. Is there any way to make this work?

**Edit:** I edited the stylesheet and hardcoded the full url of the font file into it, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: So the problem is that the font isn't loading, right? In my html file I specify path to font like this: @font-face {
    font-family: roboto;
    src: url(../../Fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf);
}. Can you try this?

Comment: The issue is that the font is referenced using a relative url from inside the `font-awesome.min.css` file. So I want to find a way to use it both in the static landing page as well as the dynamically rendered page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you may need to use the  BuildLocalStreamUri / NavigateToLocalStreamUri. In this case, the string-passed html can't refer the contents of css folder. You need to build the 'stream' that contains string, css, or other external files.
Following is an api reference:

[BuildLocalStreamUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView_BuildLocalStreamUri_System_String_System_String_)

You may need to refere the sample also. It's complicated to use.

[XAML WebView control sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7)

Comment: The issue is that the style sheet is actually loading properly and is successfully applied to the page content. The issue is the font itself. That being said, I'll try `BuildLocalStreamUri` and see how it goes.